# Installation Problem of ROS groovy on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am trying to install ROS groovy on ubuntu 11.10 by following the instruction given **http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu.** When I type in the terminal **sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full;** then after 16% completion, suddenly following errors come. And after that rosdep command does not work(command not found).

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/8979add418c3d8571af325b06392affe

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77566/installation-problem-of-ros-groovy-on-ubuntu-11.10/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2013-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a generic connectivity issue you have.  It's failing even for pure Ubuntu access.  You are probably behind a proxy or something else which is miss-configured or is possibly throttling you if you get 16% and then fail.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1